# Is possible redirect by microservice?

Tags: nginx

Can I set a variable with an URL returned by a proxy? ... I want to avoid to run Java, PHP, Python etc. Need somethong simple and faster.

Note, to answer comments: "... an URL returned by a proxy" = a microservice that is a [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) returning the URL. Any URL, can be aleatory or function of inputs (passed to the proxy).

---

### If it is possible, how to?

This is fine on my NGINX server, it is returning a string with the necessary URL.

```
    location /_test {
      rewrite ^/_test/(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

(here  `$1`  is the input and `127.0.0.1:3000` the black-box microservice)

... How to redirect as `return 301 $theNewUrl`? Imagining something (illustrative and wrong of course) as

```
    location /_test {
      rewrite ^/_test/(.*) /$1 break;
      set theNewUrl = proxy_pass(http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1);
      return 301 $theNewUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't the website you're proxying do the 301?

Comment: Hi @tkausl, see the `$1`,  the microservice (at `127.0.0.1:3000`)  recives its endpoint parameters, and decides the correct URL to be redirected. Imagine `http://myDomain/_test/Hello!`  redirecting to http://stackoverflow.com and `http://myDomain/_test/Bye` to http://w3c.org

Comment: Hello peter, I've redirected to microservices with nginx, can you clarify me with a simple example what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LuigiLopez I edited enhancing the "black-box" component ... see the pseudo-code line `theNewUrl = proxy_pass(http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1)`. The microservice computes a magic string that is a function of $1,  an infinitally variable input string.

Comment: @LuigiLopez, the real complex case (questions must be simplifications), in the problem of the real life, the microservice at port 3000 is the   http://postgrest.org , a database and some logic to process the inputs, not a simple list of "from to" translations.

Answer (score -1):

To redirect base on path on Ningx, try this:

example.com is your base domain.

```
server { 

server_name myDomain; 

 location /_test/hello/ {
       proxy_pass http://google.com/;
 }

 location /_test/bye/ {
        proxy_pass http://stackoverflow.com/;
 }
}
```

Example:

HTTP request to `http://myDomain/_test/hello/$1` will be translated to: `http://google.com/$1` you can use it with ports or whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry this is not a solution to the problem, this examples was for "imagine" to a comment that ignored `$1` , the microservice is a [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box).  It was also reinforced by the "imagine example" `set theNewUrl = proxy_pass(http://127.0.0.1:3000);`

Comment: What do you need to achieve?

Comment: Whatever input you put on "example.com/test/hello/$x" will be pased to the microservice like "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$x"

Comment: I edited the question to enhance the "black-box" component... Plase read again and  say what is wrong with the question's text that I will edit again... You can edit also, sorry my English.

Comment: Read my last comment about the input and tell me if that is what you want to achieve

Comment: Let's use exactly the syntax used in  the question to avoid confusion... The question used the example `http://myDomain/_test`.... And `$1`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192500/discussion-between-luigi-lopez-and-peter-krauss).